# Resize bitmap to create icon

Tags: android, bitmap

I am resizing a bimap image of a view I create.

```
Bitmap image = imageCreate( getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() );
image = imageResize( image, 62, 62 );
imageSave(image,"test.png");
```

The resizing takes place inside my custom view.

```
protected Bitmap imageCreate( int width, int height ) {

    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    draw(canvas);
    return image;
}

protected Bitmap imageResize(Bitmap image, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedImage;
}
```

Finally I save the image:

```
protected boolean imageSave( Bitmap image, String filename, Context context ) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

My question is, why is the image quality so god damn awful!???

The image is kind of pixelated. The original image is fantastic.

Also is there a better way?

Comment: What folder are you keeping/retrieving your bitmap image in?

Comment: @BlaineAnderson Internal storage /data/data/my app/file

Comment: Have you tried keeping the image in your res/drawable folder? Depending on your device screen resolution, you would put it in drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc...

Comment: @BlaineAnderson Internal storage is perfect for what I am doing. Wouldn't be possible to dynamically store in drawable anyway.

Comment: I don't think where you're storing matters.  You're resizing to 62 x 62, a very small image, what is the size of the original?  Also, I don't think passing 90 to the image.compress function helps, use 100 for this function.

Comment: @CSmith Original is 322x322. I read somewhere there is little difference between 90-100 with png. All the same I have already tried that and it still looks crap.

Comment: I think its becasue the icon is too small? Resize to 161x161 looks great. The lower you go the worse it gets!

Comment: Please also try Ian's suggestion, or createScaledBitmap with the filter parameter set to true.  This might apply dithering to give you better quality output.

Comment: *The image is kind of pixelated*, can you explain how you are viewing the original and resized?  For instance, if you are viewing both in an ImageView that stretches them to the same size on the screen, pixelation is what we'd expect.

Comment: @Error454 There is no streching. The image is resized to 62x62 and then I view the image at that size.

Answer (score 0):

This code

// RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP    
Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

Set the last argument to true to enable filtering.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Ian - I had already tried that and it made no difference from what I could see.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, I beleive I'm trying to shrink it too small.